# Not able to select the Radio button

Tags: javascript, protractor

```
<label for="exampleFormControlRadio1">Employment Status: </label>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" id="inlineRadio1" name="inlineRadioOptions" type="radio" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Student</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" id="inlineRadio2" name="inlineRadioOptions" type="radio" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Employed</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" disabled="" id="inlineRadio3" name="inlineRadioOptions" type="radio" value="option3">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Entrepreneur (disabled)</label>
</div>
```

My script:

```
function OP2(Status){
  element.all(by.css("label[class='form-check-label']")).each(function(item2){
    item2.getAttribute('value').then(function(status){
      console.log(status);
      if(status === Status) {
        item2.click();
      }
    });
  });
}
it('Submiting the Form', function () {
  OP2('Employed');   // here my aim is to select the EMPLOYED radio button
  // element.all(by.name('inlineRadioOptions')).get(1).click();
  browser.sleep('5000');
});
```

"Null" is displaying in the output and Radio button is not selected.
NO error message is displayed in the output.
Can anyone please help me in solving the issue.

Comment: why do you think you need to use 'value' attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Use id if you know which RB you want to select. And I see you know because you wrote.
attach more details if this does not work.Like error code, stack trace,...

// element.all(by.name('inlineRadioOptions')).get(1).click();

browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.id('inlineRadio2'))).perform();
element(by.id('inlineRadio2')).click();

Answer (score 0):

`lable` is not editable html element, you should use 'getText()' to read display text on it.

If it's `textarea` or `input type=text` you should use `getAttribute('text')`

```
function OP2(Status){
  element.all(by.css("label[class='form-check-label']")).each(function(item2){
    item2.getText().then(function(status){
      console.log(status);
      if(status === Status) {
        item2.click();
      }
    });
  });
}
```